# Bug on factor DB?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers, math-software

Maybe , this question would better be asked in another forum. If yes, what is the proper one ?

Here

https://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000000900921624

the factor database seems to have a bug! The number is prime, but it is displayed to be composite.

> Does anyone know this site and how to report or remove bugs there ?

Comment: Maple says it's composite. What makes you think it's prime?

Comment: $$111111111111111111111111111111111111061$$ is prime according to PARI/GP

Comment: The number shown in the link is the ID-number, not the number to be factored. The ID-number is trivially compositive (it is even and greater than $2$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n  = (10^{39}-451) \text{ mod } {\displaystyle{\frac{10^{39}-1}{9}}}$

$\qquad\; = 111111111111111111111111111111111110661$

Then $2^{n-1} \text{ mod }n$ reduces to

$\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\,\, 78402869353071463352746795182243243082$

hence, by Fermat's little Theorem, $n$ is not prime.

So, the "bug" is probably just a typo in how they showed the base-10 expansion of $n$.

Comment: Or maybe the order of operations is different between the component that finds the decimal expansion and the component that tests primality? The displayed number is `((10^39-451)%(10^39-1))/9`.